# Sybase ASA 9 Trigger after insert get new row

Tags: triggers, sybase, sybase-asa

By using trigger I want to copy new added record to another table. I use the follow trigger but it is not bringing values from new added row.

```
ALTER TRIGGER "SalesTRG" after insert  on
DBA.SalesTransaction_Archive
REFERENCING NEW AS new_salestransaction
for each row
WHEN ( new_salestransaction.LocCreatedClientNumber = '0001' )
BEGIN 
  insert into SalesFG(TransactionNumbers) select TransactionNumber from  new_salestransaction 
END
```

Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

the insert inside your trigger should look like:

```
insert SalesFG(TransactionNumbers) values(new_salestransaction.TransactionNumber)
```

Be aware, the trigger will be fired only when you insert new record with LocCreatedClientNumber = '0001'